# Does the Heartbleed vulnerability affect signed java applets

Tags: windows, webserver, apache, heartbleed

I have a Windows based server that serves a signed JAVA applet. The website isn't secured (HTTP), but all JAVA applets have to be signed now, so the site serves a signed JAVA applet as part of a web page. As such, the applet would have access to the client computer.

I can't explicitly find OpenSSL anywhere on the server, but I'm unclear if Apache (on Windows) somehow has it built in, and if the applet is vulnerable to this exploit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like keeping this simple.

If the webserver runs OpenSSL 1.0.1 through 1.0.1f and accepts SSL connections, it will most likely be vulnerable. As Steven says, this is SSL/TLS protocol wich is transport layer security.

This exploit is not on the application layer of the OSI layer.

Have a look at heartbleed.com for detailed information about the exploit.

Comment: I've read the details on heartbleed.com.  It still wasn't clear whether my server is vulnerable - hence my question here.  According to [this article] (http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/04/10/many_clientside_vulns_in_heartbleed_says_sans/), the server could just have non-port-443 software that was compiled against the bug, and be vulnerable.

Comment: If it doesnt use the entire OpenSSL lib, it is possible that it isnt vulnerable.

Grab a clone of https://gist.github.com/takeshixx/10107280
And test it against your application/server is my best advice

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting the web site in Internet Information Services (IIS), you won't be affected because IIS doesn't use OpenSSL to support the [SSL/TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) protocol. See [Vulnerability Note VU#720951](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/720951) for reference.

Not sure what SSL/TLS implementation Apache for Windows uses, though. Chances are it does use OpenSSL, in which case you'll want to apply a security patch as soon as possible.